# Why can't i boot directly from a disk image i made?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu, virtualization

I had a Kubuntu 16.04.3 installed on a computer but it was slow, so I put it's HDD into an enclosure and dd-ed it. The command was `sudo dd if=/dev/sdh of=/mnt/KUBUNTU.IMG; sync`. After that was done, I converted the raw .img file to VDI (because VirtualBox refused to accept any other formats) with `sudo qemu-img convert -O vdi /mnt/KUBUNTU.IMG /mnt/KUBUNTU.VDI` to transfer the users' data to the new system. After booting the VM, I was greeted by VirtualBox's EFI shell. Inserting Super Grub2 Disk's EFI version and restarting, it could find the files on hd0, gpt2 and I could start the system. The system is normally bootable again, after reinstalling GRUB.

So my question is, why can't I boot it directly without an additional bootloader?

Comment: If the old computer was legacy and virtualbox is set to efi, then that is it.

Comment: The computer is not that old. It has EFI and EFI boot is enabled. In fact, it's stuck in EFI mode since I can't access it's BIOS screen anymore. But didn't you read: the boot files are located on **hd0, gpt2**. And usually, the 2nd gpt partition is the EFI boot partition.